# Simplification of Integrals with different limits

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

Is there a way to coerce Mathematica to join two integrals (with the same integrand) together? The simplest case is:

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}] + Integrate[f[x], {x, 1, 2}]
```

Clearly, this should be equal to `Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 2}]`.

This arose in solving a linear differential equation:

```
sys = D[y[t], t] == a y[t] + b u[t];
DSolve[{sys, y[0] == 0}, y[t], t]
```

[image]

This is a nice answer, but if you look at the form, the expressions inside the two integrals are identical. Thus y[t] ought to simplify to

[image]

But I cannot seem to get Mathematica to join the two integrals together. I've tried Simplify, FullSimplify, Expand, under a variety of assumptions, but can't seem to find a way to convince Mathematica to join the two together.

Answer (score 4):

For this one, a brute force method can work

```
Unprotect@Integrate;
Integrate/:Integrate[ft_,{K[1],1,0}]-Integrate[ft_,{K[1],1,t}]:=-Integrate[ft,{K[1],0,t}];
Protect@Integrate;
```

And now

```
sys = D[y[t], t] == a y[t] + b u[t];
sol = y[t] /. First@DSolve[{sys, y[0] == 0}, y[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can change the above definition in the protect code, to make it more general, as I have hardcoded the limits for this specific problem.

Comment: It always makes me nervous changing the definitions of built-in functions.

Comment: @bills I agree with you. But I do not know any other way. btw, Maple generates the short version directly. Here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mv045.png)

Comment: @bills No risk, no fun! ;o)