# Impose integration rules

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

Suppose I have the following sum of integrals:

```
(Integrate[E^K[1]*(f2[K[1]] + x1[K[1]]), {K[1], 1, t}] - 
    Integrate[E^K[1]*(f2[K[1]] + x1[K[1]]), {K[1], 1, t0}])/
  E^t // TraditionalForm
```

Clearly, the sum can be simplified by interchanging the limits of the second integral with an additional minus and then rewrite it as a single integral (for `t0<1`).

Mathematica, however, doesn't do it automatically with `Simplify` or `FullSimplify`. I tried to invoke it with manual rules like

```
intRule1 = Integrate[a_, {b_, c_, d_}] :> -Integrate[a, {b, d, c}];
intRule2 = 
  Integrate[a_, {b_, c_, d_}] + Integrate[a_, {b_, d_, e_}] :> 
   Integrate[a, {b, c, e}];
```

But this is mostly inconvenient since I need to apply the rule manually wherever I need it. Is there a better way to make this simplification mostly automatically?

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161347) is related, if not a dupe.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of this. Then it seems you really need to force Mathematica do it. I was hoping for some assumption settings or so...

Comment: try working with  `TransformationFunctions`  (not mentioned in the linked dup but  search, there may be another related question )